# The full understandable name for a type of a generic class

Tags: scala

It's common to use full names in abstract classes for abstract types:

```
abstract class MyClass {
  type MyType
}
```

I wonder, isn't a good practice to do the same for generic classes:

```
abstract class MyClass[MyType] {

}
```

What I have seen is only this:

```
abstract class MyClass[T] {

}
```

What if I have to use a generic class and want to use the full name of its parameter, would it fit Scala's name convention:

```
abstract class MyClass[MyGenericType] {

}
```

?

Comment: "would it fit Scala's name conversion" I suppose you mean "name convention".

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with doing it that way.  The reason you don't see it frequently is that usually the parameter doesn't need a descriptive name.  For example, `List[T]` is a `List` of `T` items.  Having it be `List[Item]` doesn't really add anything.

On the other hand, there are places in the scala library where you do see more descriptive names.  Take the definition of `map`, for example:

```
def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
```

Here we see that `Repr` and `That` are both given names that are more than the standard single-letter.  Presumably this is because the authors thought it would be beneficial to make the use of these parameters clearer, since the behavior of `map` using `CanBuildFrom` is not super clear (and definitely less clear than just knowing that `T` is an item in a `List`).

I use this regularly when I think it will make things clearer.  For example, I might have a class `Tagger[Word,Tag]` because I think it's easier to read than `Tagger[A,B]` or even `Tagger[W,T]`.

Comment: If there are type-bounds (especially structural-type bounds), you tend to see more descriptive names.

Comment: Also note the [Scala Style Guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#type_parameters_generics) document. In particular use single upper case letters beginning with `A` (not `T` as in Java)